# a list of named terms from SMT-LIB v2 format of unsat core track

Tags: z3

How to use z3 api recording or printing out the terms with name list such as "a_*uc*_1" and amounts of name lists?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Could you improve the question and provide a small example?

Comment: For instance, found out the unsat cores which are ( a__uc__1 a__uc__2 a__uc__3 a__uc__4 a__uc__5 a__uc__6 a__uc__7 ) and size is 7. Is it helpful?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: As solve the instance SMT-LIB v2 format, (set-option: produce unsat cores true) (assert ! (let ((?def0 x1)) (let ((?def1(<= 1 ?def1))) :named a__uc__1), is there an api (function)does not only reading the strings, but also the name list *a__uc__1* and count the amount of name lists? I hope it can be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API for doing what you want. This information is internally available, but it is not exposed in the API. 
It is not hard to change the Z3 code to extract this information.
Internally, the following function is used to parse SMT-LIB v2 files.

```cpp
bool parse_smt2_commands(cmd_context & ctx, 
                         std::istream & is, 
                         bool interactive = false, 
                         params_ref const & p = params_ref());
```

It is defined in the file `src/parsers/smt2/smt2parser.h`.

The `cmd_context` object is defined in the object `src/cmd_context/cmd_context.h`.

It has the following methods:

```cpp
ptr_vector<expr>::const_iterator begin_assertion_names() const;
ptr_vector<expr>::const_iterator end_assertion_names() const;
```

These two methods can be used to traverse all names used to name assertions in a SMT-LIB v2 file. Each name is internally represented as Boolean variable. 
If `ctx` is the `cmd_context`, we can traverse all names using:

```cpp
ptr_vector<expr>::const_iterator it = ctx.begin_assertion_names();
for (; it != ctx.end_assertion_names(); it++) {
   expr * n = *it;
   // do something
   // here, we just print the name
   std::cout << to_app(n)->get_decl()->get_name() << "\n";
}
```